# Pathfinder: Where did the `gz` expand to?

Tags: macos, pathfinder

Sometimes compressed files do not expand to their like directory names (e.g., `what.zip` expands to the `what` directory). How can I figure out where Pathfinder (or Finder, I think) is expanding stuff to?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to do it "after the fact," but you can use the BetterZip Quick Look Generator (a Quick Look plugin) to investigate the archive contents before expansion. This will let you see the directory name it will create on expansion.

http://macitbetter.com/BetterZip-Quick-Look-Generator

Comment: I'll check it out. As long as it handles zip and everything else, it would be cool. Otherwise I'd just use unzip from the command line.